# How to turn this bitwise operation into something that can be understood by an average Joe?

Tags: bit-manipulation

I have code that I am refactoring now:

```
this.$rangeLabel
    .html(this.label || pos)
    .css({
        left: pos,
        marginLeft: -this.$rangeLabel.width() >> 1
    });
```

I don't know why this is used there but I am sure it's just someone tried to look clever, though I don't know the purpose of it and how to convert it it to something more readable?

```
-this.$rangeLabel.width() >> 1
```

Comment: The purpose actually matters, if this was intentional for the rounding direction then this is the most obvious way to write it. But maybe it was written this way just for the lulz and the rounding doesn't matter..

Comment: Add a comment above to it saying "center the label by setting a negative margin equal to half the width, rounding down". Now an average Joe can understand it.

Comment: Why not just make it as `-this.$rangeLabel.width() / 2`?

Comment: Because that doesn't round down, instead it rounds in a browser dependent way (it doesn't round by itself, but fractional pixel measurements are rounded). Whether that matters probably depends on the rest of the CSS